# Is it OK to self-answer with an answer completely copied from another source?

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers, self-answer

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/292258/how-can-i-nominate-games-on-steam) was published and self-answered with a copy & paste from [this source](http://store.steampowered.com/SteamAwardNominations/). I honestly find that kind of actions a bit *sad* as you are just **mining rep** and **contributing nothing** but, is this an approved behaviour?

Comment: See http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12109/is-it-ok-to-mine-reputation-by-asking-about-something-new-and-answering-it-insta ?

Comment: I saw that question before posting this one but, while I'm in favour of *auto answering questions*, I'm against doing it by *Coping&Pasting* as it contributes nothing. No need to even elaborate.

Comment: As long as they attribute, it doesn't matter to us.

Comment: There's not even link to source..

Comment: There is now. Sometimes, just asking for it works.

Comment: Right, the question was just a pure example though, I don't see that kind of *Q&A* to be fair. True that then people will *upvote* or *downvote* your answer but I think it's not the way to contribute to the site.

Comment: Copypasta is a valid answer. Is it very high quality? Not really. But that's what up and downvotes are for. You can Google an answer; that's totally fine.

Comment: True that. Let's just promote *sourcing* then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self answers are supported and encouraged. If its a problem others may have, there's nothing wrong with asking and answering instantly. So long as others feel it is useful, it will get up votes.

That said, if you're answering with something pulled from elsewhere, you do have to attribute it. Not doing so is plagiarizing, and subject to summary deletion. We do try to encourage people to attribute before resorting to that, though.